# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, addeventlistener

I'm not very experienced with Javascript, but I'm running into an issue I can't understand. My code is very simple:

```
document.getElementById ('chat_line_list').addEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", LocalMain, false);

function LocalMain ()
{
    var chatList = document.getElementById('chat_line_list').lastChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML;
    chatList = chatList.replace('InfoThump', '<span class="newemo-1 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('MuskMelon', '<span class="newemo-2 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonApple', '<span class="newemo-3 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonBanana', '<span class="newemo-4 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonWatermelon', '<span class="newemo-5 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonGrape', '<span class="newemo-6 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('NotNippy', '<span class="newemo-7 emoticon"></span>');
    document.getElementById('chat_line_list').lastChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML = chatList;
}
```

The exception occurs on the last line of the LocalMain() function, when I replace the innerHTML with my newly-modified string. Is there something in this code that causes a loop or overflow?

Answer (score 5):

You are causing an infinite loop!

You are listening to DOMSubtreeModified on the element `chat_line_list`, then you update that element inside of the function attached to that event!

Comment: You're right, I can't believe I missed that. I can probably issue a quick and dirty fix by having the last line run only if the string has been modified, so the function will be called twice. Can you think of a good way to have it run only once?

Comment: Okay, I solved my problem by listening for DOMNodeInserted instead of DOMSubtreeModified. This makes sense in the context of a chat client. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
document.getElementById ('chat_line_list').addEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", LocalMain, false);

function LocalMain ()
{
    var chatList = document.getElementById('chat_line_list').lastChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML;
    chatList = chatList.replace('InfoThump', '<span class="newemo-1 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('MuskMelon', '<span class="newemo-2 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonApple', '<span class="newemo-3 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonBanana', '<span class="newemo-4 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonWatermelon', '<span class="newemo-5 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('PoisonGrape', '<span class="newemo-6 emoticon"></span>');
    chatList = chatList.replace('NotNippy', '<span class="newemo-7 emoticon"></span>');

    document.getElementById ('chat_line_list').removeEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", LocalMain);

    document.getElementById('chat_line_list').lastChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML = chatList;

    document.getElementById ('chat_line_list').addEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", LocalMain, false);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Basically you are saying that each time that element is modified, `LocalMain` should be executed. As `LocalMain` also changes the element, it is executed again, and again,...

You can try to remove the EventListener and add it again after (haven't tried so I can't tell you if it would work...)

```
function LocalMain ()
{
    var chatList = document.getElementById('chat_line_list').lastChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML;
    chatList.removeEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", LocalMain, false);
    chatList = chatList.replace('InfoThump', '<span class="newemo-1 emoticon">
    (...)
    chatList = chatList.replace('NotNippy', '<span class="newemo-7 emoticon"></span>');
    document.getElementById('chat_line_list').lastChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML = chatList;
    chatList.addEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", LocalMain, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to wait 100 microseconds before calling your function using `setTimeout()` method. This works fine for me - no errors so far.

```
    document.getElementById ('chat_line_list').addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", setTimeout(LocalMain, 100), false);
```

Please please be aware that this solution is far from being perfect. **This function is still being executed to often.**